# Datagridview Cell Style issue

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `Datagridview` in C# desktop application. When any of the cell is empty, in order to highlight it, I change the background of that particular cell to `Color.Green`

```
                if (checkString(Convert.ToString(this.UserDataTable.Rows[i].Cells[kk].Value).Trim()) == false)
                {
                    this.UserDataTable.Rows[i].Cells[kk].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    this.MandatoryField_Label.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    success = false;
                }
```

When the user enters the data in the cell, I would revert back the changes. Any idea how to do it.

One of the solution, I am thinking of is to check each cell color and then change it. I am sure, there is a better way to do it.

This did not work:

```
 this.UserDataTable.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could check the content of the cell on the CellLeave event

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((DataGridViewCell)sender).Value))
    ((DataGridViewCell)sender).Style.BackColor = Color.White;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cleanest way to handle this is to use the CellFormatting event like so (this is the only code you need, you can remove your other code):

```
dataGridView1.CellFormatting += new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellFormatting);

void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Value.ToString()))
    {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    }            
}
```